# how to use Dispatcher in WPF to make a timer

Tags: wpf, timer, dispatcher

Iam a noobi
i have this problem , i need to make a timer for my program ,which starts when the user clicks a specific button.  and then to output the countdown in to a label

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615945%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is located in the `System.Windows.Threading` Namespace.

Something like this should work:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int count = 0;
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmr = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Start();
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = count += 1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: My God that was amazing  Thank you Sooo much

Answer (score 1):

This was pulled from production so I'm sure it works:

```
...
     _Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     _Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(125);
     _Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_Timer_Tick);
     _Timer.IsEnabled = true;
     _Timer.Start();
...

    void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try {
           ...Do your thing here
         } catch (Exception x){
             Debug.WriteLine("Error: "+x);
         }
    }
```